# Variable not found in Java

Tags: java

I've just started working with some programming in java. I'm experimenting with loops and I have a problem with a for-loop where I'm having a hard time finding the mistake. Its saying that "i" is not a variable, even though i made it one in just above. Hope you guys can help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loops {
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Skriv et tal");
    int a = sc.nextInt();       
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++);
    {
        System.out.println(a + i);

    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: remove the ; behind the forloop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 for(int i=0; i<=9;i++);
                    // ^ get rid of this
```

should be

```
 for(int i=0; i<=9;i++)
```

Because of that the for statement ends there and the new block had been started there.

Comment: Whih is funnily why I dislike brace-on-new-line style of blocks, as it's obvious that there's an extra semicolon...

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the <kbd>;</kbd> behind your loop definition. It is an empty statement.